# print dataframe contains "\n" chars

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which contains "\n" to format text, how can I get output as below:

```
  key              val
0   A                x
                     y
                     z
1   B            apple
                orange
2   C             good
                   bad
                  best
```

Current demo code:

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'key': ['A','B','C'],
     'val': ['x\ny\nz','apple\norange','good\nbad\nbest']})

print(df)
```

Output:
key              val

```
0   A          x\ny\nz
1   B    apple\norange
2   C  good\nbad\nbest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first split the data in the `val` column based on "\n", then `explode` the resulting list. And after there is a small trick to set in index the key with another empty index to have a multi-index, which allow to display only once the index key.

```
df['val'] = df['val'].map(lambda x: x.split('\n'))
df = df.explode('val')
df[""] = ""
df = df.set_index(["key", ""])

print(df)
```

Using this code display the dataframe almost as you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`tabulate`](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/):

```
from tabulate import tabulate

print(tabulate(df, headers='keys', tablefmt='plain'))
```

Output:

```
    key    val
 0  A      x
           y
           z
 1  B      apple
           orange
 2  C      good
           bad
           best
```